# How to set margin for multiple textbox generate at run time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to set margin for multiple textbox generate at run time? when i generate textbox at run time margin is same for all textbox and difficult to give margin using loop. Any simple way to give margin to textbox. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: textbox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? Client app, web app, silverlight/wpf?

No matter what you do, you should keep the margin in a variable. Then if you add the checkboxes in a loop, you can increase the variable to set a new margin. (Declare the variable out of the for/foreach/each/etc loop).

```
var currentMarginX = 0;
var currentMarginY = 0;

for( var i=0; i<checkboxesNeededCount; i++)
{
    // Set the textbox location with the variable location, and increase either X or Y...
    // e.g: 
         myTextbox.location = new Point(currentMargin, currentMarginY);
         currentMarginX += 50;
         currentMarginY += 50;
}
```

The example above will put a textbox with a margin of `x=50` and `y=50`, then add another one with `x=100`, `y=100`, and so on...
You'll need to be sure (if it's needed, depending on how you're doing it) to set a new instance of the control in the for statement.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

can you not give the textboxes a class and do it using CSS?

That would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

Make a css class that can have the margin attribute and set textbox's cssclass property while it is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write in-line css like
style="margin: 5px;"